# Weird behavior of QSS and Rich text in QLabel while setting font-weight

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets, qlabel

I want to set the font-weight of a QLabel to 200(light), and for that i tried QSS and Rich Text.

### 1. QSS

I tried to use QSS to set the font-family and font-weight for a qlabel but the text remained at Normal font-weight (i.e. 400), however the weight responded as expected when font-weight was above 400.

You can see here that Font-weight 200

[image]

and Font-weight 400 has no difference:

[image]

whereas Font-weight 500 seems to produce result as expected:

[image]

#### Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Main UI code goes here
    
        stsheet2 = '''
        
        #label{
            font-family: Segoe UI;
            font-size: 22pt;
            color: #525856;
            font-weight: 200;
        }
        '''
        # Set window related properties
        self.setStyleSheet(stsheet2)

        self.label = qtw.QLabel("Sample Text")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.baseWidget = qtw.QWidget(self)
        self.baseLayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.baseWidget.setLayout(self.baseLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.baseWidget)

        self.baseLayout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

### 2. Rich Text

Another approach i used was Rich Text. This technique worked and produced light text when i added normal qlabel to the layout before the qlabel with rich text but not other way around:

#### Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Main UI code goes here
        self.label = qtw.QLabel("Sample Text")
        self.label2 = qtw.QLabel("<span style=\"color: #525856; font-family: segoe ui; font-size:22pt; font-weight:200;\">Sample Text 2</span>")

        self.baseWidget = qtw.QWidget(self)
        self.baseLayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.baseWidget.setLayout(self.baseLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.baseWidget)

        self.baseLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.baseLayout.addWidget(self.label2)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Rich Text successfully produce expected output when normal QLabel added to layout **before** rich text one.

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Main UI code goes here
        self.label = qtw.QLabel("Sample Text")
        self.label2 = qtw.QLabel("<span style=\"color: #525856; font-family: segoe ui; font-size:22pt; font-weight:200;\">Sample Text 2</span>")

        self.baseWidget = qtw.QWidget(self)
        self.baseLayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.baseWidget.setLayout(self.baseLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.baseWidget)

        self.baseLayout.addWidget(self.label2)    # Notice the change
        self.baseLayout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Rich Text fails to give expected output when normal QLabel added to layout **after** rich text one.

[image]

The behavior of both QSS and Rich Text is very confusing to me. Can someone please explain why rich text is behaving this way, why QSS seems to fail setting the font-weight below 400 and lastly, how to achieve a relatively simple task of setting a font-weight to 200(light).

- PyQt5 version 5.12
- Win 10 x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I initialized an extra empty QLabel object and added it to the base layout before adding other widgets. This helped achieve the expected behavior but i still don't know why there was the problem in the first place.